# JFormattedTextField on Mac OS not changing value

Tags: java, windows, macos, swing, jformattedtextfield

Im working on a project for a friend, a Java Swing program. For now i have done the admin mode to add items to sell and change the money value in the cash register.

For that, i added JFormattedTextField to the money. The value on the left is the current amount in their cash box, the right amount is the one after this "admin session", the middle one is the difference.
[image]
I have added Property Change Listener to the difference and new values boxes, the current box is not editable. 
When i change the right box, to get a new value after the session, the **propertyChange** function calculates the difference, when i change the difference to add or remove money, the new amount gets calculated.

Im working on Windows 10 and its working fine, just as expected. But for my buddy, who is on Mac OS, if he enters a new value in either of the two fields, it does neither change the value of the current nor of the other box. Also he can't accept the input with Enter nor in any way.
He also tried a Windows Virtual Machine (XP, i think), where at least the Text fields worked and changed value by pressing Tab, but enter still didn't work.

I guess its not directly a problem with my code, but can't pinpoint the source of the problem. And since i dont own a Mac its hard to debug this problem. 
What might be the problem here and how can i fix / avoid this?

**Edit**: Code of the example Window

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;


public class Example extends javax.swing.JFrame implements PropertyChangeListener{

    public Example() {
        NumberFormat amountFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        NumberFormatter aFF = new NumberFormatter(amountFormat);
        DefaultFormatterFactory factory = new DefaultFormatterFactory(aFF);

        jLabel1 = new JLabel();
        jLabel1.setText("Old:");

        oldCashText = new JFormattedTextField();
        oldCashText.setEditable(false);
        oldCashText.setValue((float) 15);
        oldCashText.setFormatterFactory(factory);

        jLabel2 = new JLabel();
        jLabel2.setText("Difference:");

        differenceCashText = new JFormattedTextField();
        differenceCashText.setValue(differenceCash);
        differenceCashText.addPropertyChangeListener("value", this);
        differenceCashText.setFormatterFactory(factory);

        jLabel3 = new JLabel();
        jLabel3.setText("New:");

        newCashText = new JFormattedTextField();
        newCashText.setValue(newCash);
        newCashText.addPropertyChangeListener("value", this);
        newCashText.setFormatterFactory(factory);

        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
    this.setLayout(layout);

    this.add(jLabel1);
        this.add(oldCashText);
        this.add(jLabel2);
        this.add(differenceCashText);
        this.add(jLabel3);
        this.add(newCashText);

        pack();
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        Object source = evt.getSource();
        if(source == differenceCashText){
            newCash = ((Number)differenceCashText.getValue()).floatValue() + 
                    ((Number)oldCashText.getValue()).floatValue();
            newCashText.setValue(newCash);
        }
        if(source == newCashText){
            differenceCash = ((Number)newCashText.getValue()).floatValue() - 
                    ((Number)oldCashText.getValue()).floatValue();
            differenceCashText.setValue(differenceCash);
        }

    }                   



    private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField differenceCashText;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField newCashText;
    private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField oldCashText;

    private float newCash = 0;
    private float differenceCash = 0;
}
```

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Comment: Show code of what part? I can add the part of the Text field setups and the property changed functon if that helps

Comment: Producing an example is problematic, as i can't immediately test if my example would reproduce the same problem. I would need to ask my friend (or someone else with a mac) to try it.

Comment: *"Producing an example is problematic,.."* So is getting people motivated to help. If you want that help, I suggest you go to the trouble of making the MCVE mentioned by @user180355. Better be quick though, this question has already got 3 close votes.

Comment: I added the Example JFrame, that got the same problem.

Comment: One problem you would want to fix is that putting `($4.00)` in the Difference field causes the New field to show `$11.00` instead of `$19.00`.